# How to properly end an AVCaptureSession?

Tags: ios, objective-c, qr-code, avcapturesession

I have an app with a qr code reader. I set up the scanner in ViewWillAppear:

```
// Create a new AVCaptureSession.
_session = [AVCaptureSession new];
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];

// Connect the input.
if(input)
{
    [_session addInput:input];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    return;
}

// Connect the output.
AVCaptureMetadataOutput *output = [AVCaptureMetadataOutput new];
[_session addOutput:output];
NSLog(@"%@", [output availableMetadataObjectTypes]);
[output setMetadataObjectTypes:@[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]];
[output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

// Connect the preview layer.
_previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
_previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
_previewLayer.bounds = self.view.bounds;
_previewLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));
[self.view.layer addSublayer:_previewLayer];

// Start the AVSession.
[_session startRunning];
```

I implement the delegate method like so:

```
    - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

    // Iterate through all the visible metadata objects.
    for (AVMetadataObject *metadata in metadataObjects) {

        // Only care about QR codes.
        if ([metadata.type isEqualToString:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]) {

            // Parse the QR code.
            AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *transformed =
            (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[_previewLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:metadata];

            // Stop the session.
            [_previewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
            [_session stopRunning];

            // Do other stuff, then push next view controller.
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run this, it continues scanning the qr code multiple times after a call stop. After I navigate away I see a bunch of errors saying, "Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted." and then it crashes. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue too. as the most hardware directly related features all grabbed data goes in to a buffer. So what you are experiencing after stopping the session are the last frames grabbed from the camera and put into a queue. The solution (quick and dirty) is to create a BOOL variable (static or iVar) that change its states right before stop running and check its state at the beginning of the delegate method. 
 I don't have the doc in my hand now but I'm pretty sure that you can ask the session directly for its states with a `running` property and an `interrupted` property